# $1+\sqrt{2}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$. True or False

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I believe that the statement is True, and this is my argument:

Since there exists an element $((1-\sqrt{2})/(1-(\sqrt{2})^2)\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ such that their products gives $1$ (multiplicative identity), therefore ( $1+\sqrt{2}$ ) is a unit.

A $unit$ is an element $a\in R|ab=1$ where as $b\in R$. Where $b$ is known as the multiplicative inverse of $a$.

Is my argument reasonable enough? And if there is/are any other possible argument, It would be really helpful to know.

Comment: $R$ is a ring. Sorry

Comment: Your ring is in fact a field.

Comment: That's the best argument to make.

Comment: Ah... That's a weird way of writing 2 ;-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez it is indeed :)

Comment: Note that $1+\sqrt 2$ is a unit not only in ${\bf Q}[\sqrt 2]$, but also in ${\bf Z}[\sqrt 2]$.

Comment: @tomasz , does it imply that since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, it can then be used as a unit in $\mathbb{Q}$ also, that is, if it exists in the subset then it does also in the set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you have a field, so all non-zero elements are units.

But since you asked: to show that $1+\sqrt{2}$ is a unit, you just have to find an element $b$ such that $(1+\sqrt{2})b = 1$. And you can do
$$
(1 + \sqrt{2})(-1+\sqrt{2}) = -1 - \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2} + 2 = 1.
$$
And that is it. You don't have to say anything else. It just has to be clear that the $b$ is indeed an element of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$. And since $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] = \{a + b\sqrt{2}: a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$, it is very clear that $-1 + \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: Now why didn't I think of $(-1+\sqrt{2})$ , Thanks @Thomas

Comment: Just one question, since $a,b \in Q$, doesn't imply that it has to be in the form of fraction?

Comment: @Ozahm: Remember that all integers are rational numbers. $1 = \frac{1}{1} \in \mathbb{Q}$. So no, the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ don't have to be written as fractions.

Comment: thank you. But would it be more correct if it were to be described that "all integers can be expressed as rational numbers" or is it just the same thing?

Comment: @Ozahm: It is correct to say that "Any integer is a rational number". In the same way we also say that a rational number is a real number. This is perfectly fine. That said, if you define your rational numbers as equivalence classes of integers, then you could make the argument that you should distinguish.

Comment: okay, can it also be that: "Every integer is a rational number, but not every rational is an integer" ? As though as it is one-sided only?

Comment: @Ozahm: Right, not every rational number is an integer. Neither is every real number a rational number and so on.

Comment: once again, thanks.

Comment: @Ozahm: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this exercise is a warmup for the proof that $\,\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]\,$ is a field. The key idea is simple: to invert $\,w = 1+\sqrt{2}\,$ simply *rationalize the denominator* of $\,\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt 2},\,$ i.e. multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate $\,w' = 1-\sqrt{2}\,$ to force the denominator to be *rational* $\,ww' = r.\,$ Being a nonzero rational, $\,r\,$ is invertible, which yields the sought inverse $\, \dfrac{1}w = \dfrac{w'}{ww'}= r^{-1} w'$

Thus, by taking norms $\,w\to ww',$ this method transforms the problem of inverting a quadratic *irrational* to the simpler problem of inverting a *rational*. Since the same method works for any irrational $\,w = a + b\sqrt{2} \in \Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]\,$ we infer that $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$ is a field. Note that in this general proof it is crucial to show that the denominator $\,ww'= a^2-2b^2 \ne 0.\,$ But if it $=0\,$ then  $\, 2 = (a/b)^2\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$